# How can I design a data structure which the attribute path and value in Java?

Tags: java, android

I need to handle some parameters from URL, a parameters include two attributes  path and value, so I design the following data structure MURLPar.

but I don't think it's a good desgin, is there a better way? Thanks!

```
MURLPar mURLPar=new  MURLPar();
mURLPar.diskindex.value="3";
Utility.LogError("Path: "+mURLPar.diskindex.path+" Value: "+mURLPar.diskindex.value);
```

Here's the class

```
public class MURLPar {
    public class MAttrir {
        public String path;
        public String value;
    }

    public MAttrir diskcount;
    public MAttrir diskindex;


    public MURLPar(){
        diskcount=new MAttrir();
        diskindex=new MAttrir();

        diskcount.path=mContext.getString(R.String.myCount);
        diskindex.path=mContext.getString(R.String.myindex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a HashMap?

Comment: I need to save both name and value

Comment: That's what a hash map does.  It maps name->value

Comment: Such as Utility.LogError("Path: "+mURLPar.diskindex.path+" Value: "+mURLPar.diskindex.value), I need to access both path and value

Comment: the name is a constant right?

Comment: Yes, the name ( path) is  constant, which is from R.String resource. Maybe I change the path in string resource file instead of hard code

Comment: I still don't see the case against a Hashmap if the path name is constant. `map.get("Delldiskindex")` might return 3

Comment: To  cricket_007: I f I use map, I can't get the path. In my code, I can use mURLPar.diskindex.path to get the path!

Comment: I store path name in string resource file, in future, maybe I change path name, so I can't use hard code

Comment: `HashMap<Path, String>`